# vuetify custom component with datepicker events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

i have created my own vuetify component in a new page, i have a button to open a vuetify dialog box, which displays a form with a datepicker. In this date picker, i want to be able to provide custom css classes according to dates

see here for the example i used till now : https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/LYYyNYd

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      availableDates: ["2019-10-02", "2019-10-8", "2019-10-11"],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setColor() {
            let allDates = document.querySelectorAll(".v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content");

      allDates.forEach((x, i) => {
        if (i % 4 === 0) {
          allDates[i].classList.add('J1');
        }

        if (i % 4 === 1) {
          allDates[i].classList.add('J2');
        }

      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  this.setColor();
}
})
```

Be aware that normally we open a dialog box which displays this datepicker. And when we change month/year we want the css classes to be shown on new month. I tried to investigate the use of "watch" but no success till now. I would like to intercept the datepicker "open" event to be able to add the needed css classes but i feel this is too much close of the old jquery way. Till now i used this : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

I'am a vuejs newbie.

thanks for your help